# How do I convert response to my entity object

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Environment**: VS2015 Console app

How do I convert the response to my entity object?

Article was found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/a-few-great-ways-to-consume-restful-apis-in-c), under WebClient Class.

Also was wondering what JArray is? I found something in Newtonsoft.JSON and MS MVC.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
var response = client.DownloadString("https://api.github.com/repos/restsharp/restsharp/releases");
var releases = JArray.Parse(response);
```

Comment: From the article: `We are going to utilize the help of the Json.NET library to deserialize the response we get`. It is probably a method they made for deresializing.

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times on SO. Search google for `site:stackoverflow.com c# deserialize json model`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize complex object of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339167/)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package this way.

```
YourEntity entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourEntity>(response);
```