# How to read sections of JSON document?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON document and I want to access the details of the STATUS SECTION but it keeps returning null.

JSON Data is as shown:

```js
{ 
   "results":[ 
      { 
         "messageId":"15712480583306574",
         "to":"",
         "from":"TestServer",
         "sentAt":"2019-10-16T17:47:38.368+0000",
         "doneAt":"2019-10-16T17:47:38.370+0000",
         "smsCount":1,
         "mccMnc":"null",
         "price":{ 
            "pricePerMessage":0.0,
            "currency":"USD"
         },
         "status":{ 
            "groupId":5,
            "groupName":"REJECTED",
            "id":8,
            "name":"REJECTED_PREFIX_MISSING",
            "description":"Number prefix missing"
         },
         "error":{ 
            "groupId":0,
            "groupName":"OK",
            "id":0,
            "name":"NO_ERROR",
            "description":"No Error",
            "permanent":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

C# Code is:

```c#
string JsonData = response.Content.ToString();
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonData);
var statuses = results.status;
foreach(var stat in statuses) {
  string groupname = stat.groupName.Value;
  string name = stat.name.Value;
  string description = stat.description.Value;

}
```

It keeps returning null, How can I access these members? I am using Newtonsoft.

Comment: Well first off, `status` is an object, not a collection, why do you expect to be able to iterate over it?

Comment: You may want to consider using [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) instead of deserializing to `dynamic`...

Comment: @maccettura  results.status returns the null based on checks so iteration or not, it just keeps returning null

Comment: @KevoyWalters I was hoping my comment would give you the "ah ha" moment... If `results` is your json collection property, what do you expect your C# `results.status` to give you?  Heretic Monkey is right, if you deserialized into a concrete class your problem would be more apparent (since what you are doing now wouldnt compile if you were using concrete objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the status object property you need to rewrite your whole code.

```cs
string JsonData = response.Content.ToString();
var input = JObject.Parse(str);

var results = input["results"].Children();
var status = results.First()["status"];
string groupname = status["groupName"].ToString();
string name = status["name"].ToString();
string description = status["description"].ToString();

Console.WriteLine(groupname);
Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.WriteLine(description);
```

The result in Console

> REJECTED
>
> REJECTED_PREFIX_MISSING
>
> Number prefix missing

But I would rather use concrete class. You need to create multiple classes. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339167/how-do-i-deserialize-a-complex-json-object-in-c-sharp-net) is good example.

```cs
public class Envelope
{
    public List<Item> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

After that the usage is much simpler.

```cs
string JsonData = response.Content.ToString();
MyEnvelope envelope = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEnvelope>(JsonData);
var status = envelope.results[0].status;
Console.WriteLine(status.GroupName);
Console.WriteLine(status.Name);
Console.WriteLine(status.Description);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Finest Option: Create A model for the JSON.**

```
public class Price
{
    public double pricePerMessage { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool permanent { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string messageId { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public DateTime sentAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime doneAt { get; set; }
    public int smsCount { get; set; }
    public string mccMnc { get; set; }
    public Price price { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

Then do `RootObject results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonData);`

**Fair Option: Get the exact JToken you want.**

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonData = "{\"results\":[{\"messageId\":\"15712480583306574\",\"to\":\"\",\"from\":\"TestServer\",\"sentAt\":\"2019-10-16T17:47:38.368+0000\",\"doneAt\":\"2019-10-16T17:47:38.370+0000\",\"smsCount\":1,\"mccMnc\":\"null\",\"price\":{\"pricePerMessage\":0.0,\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"status\":{\"groupId\":5,\"groupName\":\"REJECTED\",\"id\":8,\"name\":\"REJECTED_PREFIX_MISSING\",\"description\":\"Number prefix missing\"},\"error\":{\"groupId\":0,\"groupName\":\"OK\",\"id\":0,\"name\":\"NO_ERROR\",\"description\":\"No Error\",\"permanent\":false}}]}";
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

        Console.WriteLine(jObject.SelectToken("results[0].status"));
    }
}
```