# How to deserialize below json array

Tags: c#-4.0

```
  // Json
        {
          "application": [
            "java.util.arraylist",
            [
              {
                "applicationId": "XXXX"        
              }
            ]
          ],
          "applicationType": "ZZZZ",
          "functionType": "YYYY"
        }
```

I have created the below property for above JSON

```
    public class Root
         {
             public Application[] Application { get; set; }
             public string ApplicationType { get; set; }
             public string FunctionType { get; set; }
         }

         public class Application
         {
            public string something { get; set; }
            public SubApplication[] SubApplicationItem { get; set; }
         }

         public class SubApplication
         {
             public string applicationId { get; set; }            
         }
```

Not sure how should I create a property for below part of the JSON, Can someone please share your thoughts on this

> [
>           "java.util.arraylist",
>           [

Comment: Welcome to SO! Whoever wrote the api you are calling should clean it up, it should never have "java.util.arraylist" as a key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deserialize a complex JSON object in C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339167/how-do-i-deserialize-a-complex-json-object-in-c-sharp-net)