# Deserialize JSON in c# - what is wrong?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying without success to deserialize this JSON in c#:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "path": "http:\/\/www.igormasin.it\/fileuploads\/tanja_23a6id"
    },
    "files": [{
        "file": "\/IMG_0992-Edit_a.jpg"
    }, {
        "file": "\/IMG_1024-Edit_a.jpg"
    }, {
        "file": "\/IMG_1074-Edit_a.jpg"
    }, {
        "file": "\/Untitled-1.jpg"
    }]
}
```

my code:

```
public class JsonTxt
{
    public IList<string> settings { get; set; }
    public IList<string> files { get; set; }
}
```

downloadstring contains the Json text:

```
 var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTxt>(downloadString);        
 Console.WriteLine("*************************************************");
 Console.WriteLine(deserialized.settings[0].ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(deserialized.files.Count);
```

exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. 
{"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]' because the type 
requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized 
type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type 
like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also 
be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'settings.path', line 1, position 20.'
```

I am not able to understand the error, and what I am suposed to do.. From what I understand IList is wrong, but what else would be the correct thing to write?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but [sites like json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) can help you with your classes if you're having problems visualising the JSON as objects

Comment: The items in your `files` array in the JSON are objects with a property called `file` rather than simply an array of strings, ditto `settings`.

Comment: Simply put your type `JsonTxt` and the json text you want to deserialize do not match. Both the property `settings` and the property `files` are very different between what is defined and what you are trying to assign.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you very much this is amazing..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deserialize a complex JSON object in C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339167/how-do-i-deserialize-a-complex-json-object-in-c-sharp-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class structure needs to be something like this:

```
public class JsonTxt
{
    public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    public IList<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class Settings
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

`Settings` is an object, not a collection, and `Files` is a collection of objects not strings.

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked! will accept the answer as soon as the system lets me do it

Answer (score 2):

Your class type expect IList settings :

```
public class JsonTxt
{
    public IList<string> settings { get; set; }
    public IList<string> files { get; set; }
}
```

but in the json you provide is an object

```
 "settings": {
        "path": "http:\/\/www.igormasin.it\/fileuploads\/tanja_23a6id"
    },
```

you should change JsonText attributes type to match with your JSON